# Why is std::vector so much slower then array pointer

Tags: c++, opengl

Im creating a Opengl font batch draw.

I want to know why my std::vector is so much slower then using a array pointer.

I have tried adding vector reserve and everything i can think of.

My FPS drops just over half when using vectors.

Vectors seem easier to manage and look nicer in code, but im really stuck on this.

Not sure if its something simple that i have missed?

Or is it better to just use array pointers?

```
#ifdef USE_VECTORS
    std::vector<Vertex> m_vertices;
#else
    Vertex *m_pVertex;
    Vertex m_vertices[MAX_VERTICES];
#endif
```

drawing char function

```
    void GLFont::drawChar(char c, int x, int y)
    {
        //  1------4
        //  |      |            1 = (x, y)
        //  |      |            2 = (x, y + charHeight)
        //  |      |            3 = (x + charWidth, y + charHeight)
        //  |      |            4 = (x + charWidth, y)
        //  |      |
        //  |      |
        //  2------3
        //

        const Glyph &glyph = getChar(c);
        int charWidth = glyph.width;
        int charHeight = m_charHeight;

    #ifdef USE_VECTORS
        Vertex vert[] = {
            x, y,
            glyph.upperLeft[0], glyph.upperLeft[1],
            m_color[0], m_color[1], m_color[2], m_color[3],

            x, y + charHeight,
            glyph.lowerLeft[0], glyph.lowerLeft[1],
            m_color[0], m_color[1], m_color[2], m_color[3],

            x + charWidth, y + charHeight,
            glyph.lowerRight[0], glyph.lowerRight[1],
            m_color[0], m_color[1], m_color[2], m_color[3],

            x + charWidth, y,
            glyph.upperRight[0], glyph.upperRight[1],
            m_color[0], m_color[1], m_color[2], m_color[3]
        };
        //unsigned dataArraySize = sizeof(vert) / sizeof(Vertex);

        m_vertices.insert(m_vertices.end(), &vert[0], &vert[4]);

        ++m_numCharsToDraw;
    #else
         //1
        m_pVertex->x = x;
        m_pVertex->y = y;
        m_pVertex->s = glyph.upperLeft[0];
        m_pVertex->t = glyph.upperLeft[1];
        m_pVertex->r = m_color[0];
        m_pVertex->g = m_color[1];
        m_pVertex->b = m_color[2];
        m_pVertex->a = m_color[3];
        ++m_pVertex;

        // 2
        m_pVertex->x = x;
        m_pVertex->y = y + charHeight;
        m_pVertex->s = glyph.lowerLeft[0];
        m_pVertex->t = glyph.lowerLeft[1];
        m_pVertex->r = m_color[0];
        m_pVertex->g = m_color[1];
        m_pVertex->b = m_color[2];
        m_pVertex->a = m_color[3];
        ++m_pVertex;

        // 3
        m_pVertex->x = x + charWidth;
        m_pVertex->y = y + charHeight;
        m_pVertex->s = glyph.lowerRight[0];
        m_pVertex->t = glyph.lowerRight[1];
        m_pVertex->r = m_color[0];
        m_pVertex->g = m_color[1];
        m_pVertex->b = m_color[2];
        m_pVertex->a = m_color[3];
        ++m_pVertex;

        // 4
        m_pVertex->x = x + charWidth;
        m_pVertex->y = y;
        m_pVertex->s = glyph.upperRight[0];
        m_pVertex->t = glyph.upperRight[1];
        m_pVertex->r = m_color[0];
        m_pVertex->g = m_color[1];
        m_pVertex->b = m_color[2];
        m_pVertex->a = m_color[3];
        ++m_pVertex;

        if (++m_numCharsToDraw == MAX_CHARS_PER_BATCH)
        {
            drawTextEnd();
            drawBatchOfChars();
            drawTextBegin();
        }
    #endif
    }

void GLFont::drawBatchOfChars()
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

#ifdef USE_VECTORS
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices[0].x);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices[0].s);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices[0].r);
#else
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices->x);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices->s);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &m_vertices->r);
#endif

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, m_numCharsToDraw * 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: Optimization enabled?

Comment: Are you building in release mode (=with optimizations enabled)? What compiler are you using?

Comment: i was just testing in debug mode in visual studio 2015

Comment: This is unfair comparison, you shoud try std::array instead

Comment: You codes using `std::vector` and pointers are not equivalent. You fill a temp vector, then you insert elements to the resulting vector. And you do insertion in-place for pointers.

Comment: @KillzoneKid how do you mean unfair?

Comment: Debug timings roughly benchmark "how much abstraction am I using", not how fast the code will be in reality

Comment: There appears to be no drawing in the vector case.

Comment: @molbdnilo the drawing is called after printing text, the only reason there is drawing in the array case is because if the string is to large it draws it and resets the vertex array

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing apples to oranges:

- Containers contain pointers themselves, reducing locality of data.
- Containers need to reallocate storage when changing size.
- Microsoft's Visual Studio enables additional diagnostics in their standardlibrary containers. For example, accessing via `vec[123]` causes undefined behaviour per standard if the index is out of range. This allows implementing this as simple indexing via the pointer to the array's payload. With additional diagnostics, the index is validated, which is just a small comparison and a branch, but in tight loops it makes a difference.

That said, your approach to prove something is flawed. You'd first have to implement equivalent code that is reduced as far as possible (in the spirit of an MCVE). Hooking an OpenGL backend onto it isn't going to make things reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for you to see a large performance difference is Debug mode.

In Debug mode MSVC by default inlines nothing, does not store any variable in registers and always allocates and validates a stack frame, no name a few.

The extra abstractions when using a vector in Debug mode directly translate to more work for the CPU.